# Отмена обновления страницы после отправки формы в Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

Пользователь на странице заполняет форму, после нажатия на кнопку формируются данные без участия сервера и пользователь должен остаться на этой же странице в текущем состоянии(форма остается заполненной).
Для этого при вызове функции я добавил:
event.preventDefault();
Это работает в Хроме, Опере и ИЕ, но не функционирует в Лисе(форма сбрасывается в начальное состояние)
Может кто подсказать в чем проблема?

Comment: в хроме, опере,ие работает, потому что есть глобальный объект window.event... в лисе такого нету...можно відумать для лисі что-то на подобии function(event){...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var element = document.querySelector("form");
    element.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Form submission cancelled.");
    });
```

Попробуй так. У меня в Файрфоксе работает.

Comment: Спасибо! Работает)